# javax.ws.rs.core.Response.readEntity(Pet.class) results in Exception MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException

Tags: jersey, client

I am writing a REST client using jersey. 
My REST api uses custom message body writer. I am getting correct output using POSTMAN but when I tried to write a client, I am getting an exception.

```
@ApplicationPath("webapi")
public class MyApplication extends Application {

}

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("pet")
public class PetResource {

@GET
@Path("/{breed}/{name}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Pet getPet(@PathParam("breed") String breed, @PathParam("name") String name) {
    return new Pet(breed, name);
 }
}

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public class CustomMessageBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<Pet> {

@Override
public long getSize(Pet arg0, Class<?> arg1, Type arg2, Annotation[] arg3,
        MediaType arg4) {
    return -1;
}

@Override
public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type arg1, Annotation[] arg2,
        MediaType arg3) {
    return Pet.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
}

@Override
public void writeTo(Pet pet, Class<?> type, Type arg2, Annotation[] arg3,
        MediaType arg4, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> arg5,
        OutputStream out) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
    out.write(pet.toString().getBytes());

 }
}

public class Pet {
private String name;
private String breed;

public Pet() {

}

public Pet(String breed, String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.breed = breed;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getBreed() {
    return breed;
}
public void setBreed(String breed) {
    this.breed = breed;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Pet [name=" + name + ", breed=" + breed + "]";
}

}
```

REST Client code :

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class PetClient {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Client restClient = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    Response response = restClient.target("http://localhost:8085/bootstrapexample/webapi/pet/dog/rani").request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get();
    Pet pet = response.readEntity(Pet.class);
    System.out.println(pet);
  }
}
```

Exception :

```
Exception in thread "main"    org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=text/plain, type=class com.example.bootstrapexample.Pet, genericType=class com.example.bootstrapexample.Pet.
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:231)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:155)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1075)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:853)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:785)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse.readEntity(ClientResponse.java:326)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse$1.call(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:111)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:419)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse.readEntity(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:108)
at com.example.bootstrapexample.PetClient.main(PetClient.java:12)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have a `MessageBodyWriter` to handle the server side outgoing serialization, but a [`MessageBodyReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html) is needed for *incoming* deserialization.

Once you implement the reader, then register it with the `Client`

```
restClient.register(MyReader.class);
```

As an aside, a common pattern it to must make the provider class implementation both `MessageBodyReader` and `MessageBodyWriter`. That way you just have one class provider for both reading and writing.

Comment: thank you @peeskillet.  You are correct and how I verified it is, I used String class to convert my REST response in PetClient.java which worked well.        String petString = response.readEntity(String.class);  I have to write MessageBodyReader at client end to convert the response to Pet object.